# I forgot my ssh passphrase

Tags: linux, ssh

I am moving to an Apple Mac and i copied my id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files across to my new machine. When i tried to connect to remote machine over ssh it asked me to enter my password for the ssh key and I have forgotten what it is.

I used a python script to try and get it from my gnome keyring on the old machine i am migrating from but it didn't seem to be in there.

Any advice would be most welcome.

Comment: more appropriate to serverfault.com

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you forget your old passphrase, you will have to destroy the existing key pair and generate a new key pair using ssh-keygen.

Comment: in the end it turned out that i hadn't forgotten my password, i'd copied the contents of my ssh key file and somehow caused some file corruption. All sorted now :) thanks.